# My player app keeps being killed on some devices

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, foreground-service

My player app uses a foreground service for playback and yet on some devices playback is killed by the device until the app is excluded from the device Optimized apps list.
It's as if the device has a list of white listed app that won't be killed because this doesn't see to happen for big apps like Spotify, Google Music, ... and yet small player apps get killed.
This doesn't seem to be a code issue. I just want to make sure I'm not imagining this
What do you think about this

Comment: Foreground services aren't immune to being killed, they're just lower on the kill list.  They can still be killed if the foreground app needs more resources than the system can provide with those running.

Comment: I get that, but what I'm referring to is some device killing the app after 2 or 3 minutes on the clock as soon as it's in the background (still running the foreground service). This isn't related to the device resource, this is the default built-in behavior of those devices

Comment: That sounds like it isn't a foreground service.  Are you calling startForeground to start it AND calling it in the service to confirm?  calling startService (or bindService) to start it instead of startForeground or not confirming in the service itself will leave it a background service, which will see it killed in 2 or 3 minutes.

Comment: Please read my post. Yes I'm referring to a foreground service. To confirm this the notification cannot be swiped. More and more manufacturer are behaving that way since Android 8

Comment: I have read your post.  I'm saying that your behavior is exactly what I'd expect of a background service.  I'm saying you likely made a mistake and did not launch it as a foreground correctly.  By likely, I mean with 99% certainty based off your description.

Comment: And yet that's no the case. There's not a single doubt about it. Calling stop foreground causes the notification to be swipeable right away. The startForeground method is called from the service onCreate method and cannot be skipped